# how to grep unique ip addresses from file

Tags: linux, filter, grep, command, ip

I have a text file that contain some details. I want to grep the unique ip addresses and print all the tuples of that matching ip address.

Input text file contains details as follows:

```
Jan 11 11:11:11 2020-12-01 11: 11:11: {ABC-ABCDE-AB-123}ABCDEFGHI_ABCDEFG_ABCD: application:none, ab0.567 123.45.67.890:56789 [111.111.111.111:12345] ->  117.140.11.11:123 (TCP)
Jan 11 11:11:11 2020-12-01 11: 11:11: {ABC-ABCDE-AB-123}ABCDEFGHI_ABCDEFG_ABCD: application:none, ab0.567 123.45.67.890:12345 [111.111.111.111:12345] ->  110.140.11.11:123 (TCP)
Jan 11 11:11:11 2020-12-01 11: 11:11: {ABC-ABCDE-AB-123}ABCDEFGHI_ABCDEFG_ABCD: application:none, ab0.567 123.45.67.890:56789 [111.111.111.111:12345] ->  117.140.11.11:123 (TCP)
Jan 11 11:11:11 2020-12-01 11: 11:11: {ABC-ABCDE-AB-123}ABCDEFGHI_ABCDEFG_ABCD: application:none, ab0.567 123.75.88.860:98765 [111.111.111.111:12345] ->  117.140.79.118:123(UDP)
Jan 11 11:11:11 2020-12-01 11: 11:11: {ABC-ABCDE-AB-123}ABCDEFGHI_ABCDEFG_ABCD: application:none, ab0.567 123.75.88.860:98765 [111.111.111.111:12345] ->  117.140.79.118:123(UDP)
```

the output i need:

```
Jan 11 11:11:11 2020-12-01 11: 11:11: {ABC-ABCDE-AB-123}ABCDEFGHI_ABCDEFG_ABCD: application:none, ab0.567 123.45.67.890:12345 [111.111.111.111:12345] ->  110.140.11.11:123 (TCP)
Jan 11 11:11:11 2020-12-01 11: 11:11: {ABC-ABCDE-AB-123}ABCDEFGHI_ABCDEFG_ABCD: application:none, ab0.567 123.75.88.860:98765 [111.111.111.111:12345] ->  117.140.79.118:123(UDP)
```

I need the whole row and the ip must be unique

i don't care about other columns i just want all the row where ip adddress must be unique. this position ip most be unique in all output rows **123.75.88.860**:98765 [111.111.111.111:12345] ->  117.140.79.118:123(UDP)

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking for. Do you just want the first line containing each unique IP address in the input? If so, this is probably not something that POSIX `grep` alone is likely to accomplish, are you willing to use other tools?

Comment: i need all these line "Jan 11 11:11:11 2020-12-01 11: 11:11: {ABC-ABCDE-AB-123}ABCDEFGHI_ABCDEFG_ABCD: application:none, ab0.567 123.45.67.890:56789 [111.111.111.111:12345] -> 117.140.11.11:123 (TCP)" where the ip most be unique.

These ip most be unique "123.45.67.890" in  123.45.67.890:56789 [111.111.111.111:12345] -> 117.140.11.11:123

Answer (score 2):

a quick one, just check on the col#17:

```
$ awk -F' |:' '!a[$17]++' yourFile                      
Jan 11 11:11:11 2020-12-01 11: 11:11: {ABC-ABCDE-AB-123}ABCDEFGHI_ABCDEFG_ABCD: application:none, ab0.567 123.45.67.890:56789 [111.111.111.111:12345] ->  117.140.11.11:123 (TCP)
Jan 11 11:11:11 2020-12-01 11: 11:11: {ABC-ABCDE-AB-123}ABCDEFGHI_ABCDEFG_ABCD: application:none, ab0.567 123.75.88.860:98765 [111.111.111.111:12345] ->  117.140.79.118:123(UDP)
```

Comment: col#17? 
how do you count column ? by : or <space>

Comment: @BhawishyaKhanal change the awk a bit, print each column `idx: value` through a loop, you will see which value is your target.

Comment: it works for me. thank you.
cound you please explain how that command works?

Comment: @BhawishyaKhanal good to hear that works on your end. I just did a google for the explanation, hope it helps: https://iridakos.com/programming/2019/05/16/remove-duplicate-lines-preserving-order-linux

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure I fully understand your problem statement, but I don't think what you are asking can be done with the `grep` tool alone.

Perhaps this `perl` command will do what you need? (assuming input file is named `input`)

```bash
perl -ne 'BEGIN { my %seen } if (/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && ! $seen{$1}) { $seen{$1} = 1 ; print "$_" }' input
```

This should output the first line containing each unique IP address (ignoring the port number) in that first IP field. It works by pattern-matching the first substring in the line that looks like an IP address, and consulting a hash called `seen` to determine if this is the first line providing that IP address. If so, the line is output.

If this is still not what you need, please try to further clarify the question.

Comment: @BhawishyaKhanal Welcome to StackOverflow! The best way to thank a good answer is to mark it Accepted (checkmark button on the left) and up-vote it (once you have enough reputation)